# How to transfer graphically created static UITableView to implementation files

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I've created a static UITableView through storyboard, and I want to be able to control it through a UITableViewController .h and .m file. Everything is all set up in storyboard, but how do I transfer the data (sections, number of rows in each section) into the implementation files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the content or attributes of interface elements (e.g. `UILabel`, `UIImageView`) in code you should create `IBOutlets` for them and connect them.
Since this is a static table that does not have dynamic cells there is nothing wrong with that.

And you don't need the `UITableViewDataSource` methods for a static table. Just remove these methods from the implementation file.

Comment: how would I access the tableview programmatically?

Comment: create an outlet for it, no difference from a "regular" tableview. You just don't need the dataSource methods (i.e. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`, `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`). All this is handled from within the storyboard.

Comment: when I delete the numberofrows and so on, my app crashes when connected to a UITableViewController file